Apostrophes in Message Templates / Event Confirmation Email
Not a question per se, more a note of caution: if an additional text contains apostrophes (as in this year's, didn't, Alzheimer’s ) the whole bunch of the text disappears silently from emails. Be careful with orthography!
CiviCRM 5.70.0,/Smarty2.

that sounds like a bug

@Demerit perhaps, however if no  one else is complaining I'm not sure if it worth reporting.
